# Putting Field Label Inline With Field

Tags: css, label

Hello ive been struggling with this for tooooooo long and i have to ask the folks that know as i could be barking up the wrong tree entirely.

```
<div class="field field-name-field-they-say field-type-text-long field-label-above">
<div class="field-label">They Say: </div>
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">Our juiciest juice to date. It's like a watermelon at peak     ripeness, when the color is vivid and the juice drips down your face. Mellow sweetness and you can actually taste the rind. This flavor is perfect to vape at summer barbecues. It smells delicious and produces a lot of vapor.    </div>
</div>
```

Its the field-label 'they say' bit. I just want to have it inline with field-item bit that starts 'our juiciest juice to date....'

```
.field-name-field-they-say {
    background-color: #232425;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}

.field .field-label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Its taken me half an hour just to post my code above on stackoverflow so you can see what your dealing with here :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `float:left` on the field label

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/N2f4b/)**

```
.field .field-label {
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: .field-label
{
   float: left;
}

Comment: ah hah brilliant Danield. Works a treat. Dunno why i never thought of that. Thanks again :)